# How to get frames from a pygame game

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, reinforcement-learning, pygame-surface

I am trying to extract frames from my previously coded pygames module in order to train a RL Agent on it. However, I am unsure as to how to extract frames from the game engine.

More specifically, I have looked this up and found this blog post on it, however I don't really understand how I can access and wrap the pygame.display without hijacking my game object main loop.
https://danielslater.net/2015/12/29/how-to-run-learning-agents-against-pygame/

This is the game that I am trying to extract frames from:
https://github.com/Jh123x/Orbital/blob/master/Space%20Invaders/classes/game.py

Could I get some advise on how to do this?

edit: More specifically, how would i call the function to extract frames from the game loop while it is running?

**frame extractor code**

```
import pygame  
import pygame.surfarray  

 # function that we can give two functions to and will return us a new function that calls both
 def function_combine(screen_update_func, our_intercepting_func):  
   def wrap(*args, **kwargs):  
     screen_update_func(*args,  
               **kwargs) # call the screen update func we intercepted so the screen buffer is updated  
     our_intercepting_func() # call our own function to get the screen buffer  
   return wrap  

 def on_screen_update():  
   surface_array = pygame.surfarray.array3d(pygame.display.get_surface())  
   print("We got the screen array")  
   print(surface_array)  

 # set our on_screen_update function to always get called whenever the screen updated  
 pygame.display.update = function_combine(pygame.display.update, on_screen_update)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save

You could try pygame.image.save(window, "frame.png")

Where window is the active window object.

Comment: Hi, could you give an example of perhaps where i could call this from? I am asking more so where I could call such functions from from rather than what function to use, as I am not sure where I can call the functions from to extract the image array from the game loop.

Comment: How often do you want to save an image? Every frame? (Note that this is going to be a pretty slow operation). If so, you could place it in the games "update" method of the gamewindow class (using self.screen in place of window), alternatively, you could put it in mainloop anywhere under the "while running" loop. just be sure to call it on the screen object

Comment: I want to call this method without modifying the main loop of the game, and calling this method:
surface_array = pygame.surfarray.array3d(pyame.display.get_surface()) to extract frames and process them will ideally not need to write to disk and incur the slowdown as you have pointed out. Is there some way to get the display without modifying the game loop?

Comment: I can't think of any way you could do it without modifying either the main loop itself, or one of the methods mainloop calls, since it looks like mainloop doesn't relinquish control until the game has ended.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same challenge. Unfortunately pygame doesn't offer a solution for saving a frame in a variable.

All I could do was saving a png and reloading it again.

An improvement that I gave to above suggestion was this :

```
# Take a screenshot of the game window
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
screenshot_filename = f"screenshot_{current_time}.png"
pygame.image.save(window.subsurface(window.get_rect()), screenshot_filename)
```

By doing this you will save the games screenshot only and you can avoid extra pixcels around your screenshot.